# SQL query to extract information from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I need some help with a SQL query, I don't even know how to name this kind of SQL query pattern... I have the following simplified tables:

```
teachers: 
  ID | NAME
  1  | john
  2  | paul

teachers_subjects: 
  TEACHER_ID | SUBJECT_ID
  1          | 42
  1          | 43
  2          | 43


subjects: 
   ID | NAME
   42 | english
   43 | french
```

It's pretty easy: teachers can teach many subjects. Now, I need to find all the teachers that can teach both "english" and "french" (which happens to be "john"). What would be the SQL query for that?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? (Specify as formatted text here too.)

Comment: It's called a many to many relationship.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am actually using both. On my dev machine I use Mysql, while on the production server I will use Postgresql. While I would prefer a solution that works on both, the strict requirement is for the query to work on Postgresql. The expected result is not very important, I mean, a query that extracts the teachers ID is good enough for me. When I need the teacher names I can edit the query, that part is within my current capabilities :)

Answer (score 4):

I like to do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select ts.teacher_id
from teachers_subjects ts join
     subjects s
     on ts.subject_id = s.id
where s.name in ('English', 'French')
group by ts.teacher_id
having count(*) = 2;  -- the teacher teaches both languages
```

Note:  You can join in the teacher name if you want that in the output rather than the id.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to create a separate query to get teachers that teach english and teachers that teach french. If you have both of these sets you can use the intersect command to find those that are present in both sets.

The corresponding sql code would look like this:

```
(SELECT teachers.name
FROM teachers, teachers_subjects, subjects
WHERE teachers.id = teachers_subject.id AND teachers_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id and subjects.name = "english")
INTERSECT
(SELECT teachers.name
FROM teachers, teachers_subjects, subjects
WHERE teachers.id = teachers_subject.id AND teachers_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id and subjects.name = "french")
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` all the tables. Something like

```
select t.Name
from teachers t
join teachers_subjects ts on t.id = ts.teacher_id
join subject s1 on ts.subject_id = s1.id
join subject s2 on ts.subject_id = s2.id
where s1.NAME = 'English' and s2.NAME = 'French'
```